# Parse json and replace html

Tags: json, ajax

After submitting a form I'm directed to a blank page that shows some json data such as:

some error

```
{"status":0,"message":"some error message here"}
```

or success

```
{"status":1,"message":"You have been signed up!"}
```

I would like the contents of a span element to be replaced with the message from the json data.

span element:

```
<span class="ladda-label" id="notice">Get notified!</span>
```

My script is located after my jquery and is as follows

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function( data ) {
    var prices = data.message;
    $('#notice').html(data.message);
 }
   });
 });
</script>
```

I'm pretty confident I'm not doing a single thing correctly here.

Comment: I don't understand question, can you explain? Can you put other codes?

Comment: I would like the contents of a span element to be replaced with the message from the json data.

Comment: There aren't url and method in your Ajax request

Comment: You can write it as $().html(prices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...be more carefull )

```
<script>
  $.ajax('/my-data-url',{
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function( data ) {
    var prices = data.message;

    //$('#notice').text -> html( message.data !!! -> data.message);

    $('#notice').html(data.message);
     },
  error: function() {
     console.log('connection error')
  }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm still getting the white mage with just my json data (but you did get rid of my text editor warning. I've posted my current script